# How to plot odds ratio of prediction of logistic model in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic-regression

I have a logistic regression model like this

```
model4 <- glm(diabetes ~ sex*age, data = df, family = "binomial")
```

where age is a continous variable and sex determines if a patient is male or female. Diabetes is either 0 or 1. I want to vizualize the interaction by plotting the odds-ratio of the probability of patients to get diabetes as a function of age, by comparing to patients that are 50 years old.

I tried to do it by using the `predict` function on only the females in the dataset, and then only the males, and taking the exponential of these vectors. This produces some results that doesn't really make sense.

```
probabilitiesK <- predict(model4, sorteddfK,type = "response") 
probabilitiesM <- predict(model4, sorteddfM,type = "response")

#plotting the points by age, male and female separate
plot(sorteddfK$age, exp(probabilitiesK), col = "red", ylim = c(1.04, 1.20)) #plotting exp(log - odds) = odds ratio for women
points(sorteddfM$age, exp(probabilitiesM), col = "blue") #plotting exp(log - odds) = odds ratio for men
```

This produces:
[this plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7KWh.png)

I don't understand how to compare to patients that are 50 years old. I could predict for a 50 year old patient, and divide by this value, but this is just a constant so it won't change my plot's shape.
I also tried to make a new model that takes age50 = age-50, but this gives the same plot as my example code.
I think I have missed some important aspect of the odds ratio, but I have really tried to read about it and I still don't understand.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by making a function that finds the odds of my logistic regression, and dividing this with the odds of a patient of 50 years of age having diabetes.

Fist I made the logistic regression model with interaction, saved the estimates as b0,b1,b2,b3 and then made the function

Like this:

```
model5 <- glm(diabetes ~ sex*age, data = df, family = "binomial")
summary(model5)

b0 <- -1.378675 #intercept
b1 <- -2.049248 #sexK
b2 <- -0.006735 #age
b3 <-  0.022666 #sexK:age

Odds_refM0 <- function(age, sexK){
  return(exp(b0 + (b1*sexK) + (b2*age) + (b3*age*sexK)))
}

o_w_refMO <- Odds_refM0(age = sorteddfK$age, sexK = 1) #odds for women (men as reference)
o_w50_refMO <- Odds_refM0(age = 50, sexK = 1) #odds for women 50 yrs
OR_W <- o_w_refMO/o_w50_refMO # Odds ratios for women

o_m_refMO <- Odds_refM0(age = sorteddfM$age, sexK = 0) #odds for men
o_m50_refMO <- Odds_refM0(age = 50, sexK = 0) # odds for men of 50 yrs
OR_M <- o_m_refMO/o_m50_refMO # Odds ratios for men

#plotting
plot(sorteddfK$age, OR_W, type = "p", col = "red", xlim = c(20, 95), ylim = c(0.5,2), main = "Kønsspæcifik alderseffekt ifht alder = 50, kvinder: rød, mænd: blå", xlab = "alder", ylab = "OR")  +
points(sorteddfM$age, OR_M, type = "p", col = "blue")
```